# Send variables to iOS from PHP push notification?

Tags: php, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using a PHP script to send push notifications to my device. Here is what I use

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'id' => '10'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

echo "to $deviceToken.";

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I get it successfully. I tap the view button, and I am trying to read the 'id' variable like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Check for push notification info  
NSDictionary *pushInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];  
if (pushInfo)  
{  
    // TODO: Pull the poke's info from our server and update the UI to display it  
    NSLog(@"Here's the id: %@", [pushInfo valueForKey:@"id"]);  
}

return YES;
}
```

However, I don't get a NSLog when in mutitasking. I have yet to try it when I close the app because I cannot run console after you close out.

I even tried this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
// Handle the notificaton when the app is running
NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);
}
```

If I send the notification when running, I don't even get a NSLog. What's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *pushInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"] objectForKey:@"aps"]];
```

Comment: Using a string literal is probably not the correct solution; the constant symbol `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` is defined in Apple's UIApplication.h header file; I would be cautious of eschewing pre-defined symbols as the really are part of the well-defined, public API.